# GWT RPC Security

Tags: java, security, gwt, rpc

Its my first question here so I hope I'm describing my problem correctly.

I got application with Java EE Beans on backend and GWT on FrontEnd. Application Server is Wildfly. I'm making RPC calls from GWT to servlets.
Appliation is only filling form and sending fields' values to server.

My question: Is it secure to send important data with RPC calls as I don't want anyone to catch information or change anything while sending?

Comment: Use POST method when sendig data to server, configure https and disable http... security is a large topic, depends really what you are doing and how sensible your data is. Also how the backed is handling the incoming data.

Comment: In my company we also use HTTPS and secured the service methods that get called from RPCImpls with Spring `@PreAuthorize` annotations